# Suddenly no new confirmations on bitcoind

Tags: bitcoind, confirmations

I'm using version `40000` of bitcoind and yesterday it stopped receiving new confirmations. Here is the `getinfo` for it.

```
 "version" : 40000,
 "balance" : x,
 "blocks" : 225454,
 "connections" : 8,
 "proxy" : "",
 "generate" : false,
 "genproclimit" : -1,
 "difficulty" : 4367876.00084220,
 "hashespersec" : 0,
 "testnet" : false,
 "keypoololdest" : 1362824413,
 "keypoolsize" : 101,
 "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
 "errors" : "URGENT: upgrade required, see http://bitcoin.org/dos for details"
```

My blkindex.dat is currently 7.89GB (split over 5 files) and database log c. 12GB.

What should I do to fix this? 
I see that it's recommended to upgrade due to a DOS vulnerability but unless I am sure that this is the cause of the problem I don't want to go to the trouble of changing the setup.

Comment: Pastebin of Debug.log might help.

Comment: Your post on the BitcoinTalk forum with responses: http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=153371.0